# Fazer várias consutas sql numa só query

Tags: cakephp

Olá.

Quero fazer uma busca por despesas inseridas na tabela despesas. Eu quero fazer na mesma query: somar as despesas encontradas de acordo com os parâmetros de busca, contar quantas despesas foram encontradas também de acordo com os parâmetros passados e retornar esse total, a quantidade e o custo de cada despesa.

Quando eu não uso as funções sum e count, todas as despesas vêm. Mas quando eu uso qualquer uma delas, vem o total ou a quantidade correta, mas só lista a primeira despesa.

Estou usando cakephp 2.4 e a query é:

```
$despesas = $this->Despesa->query("select sum(despesas.valor_despesa) as total, count(id_despesa) as quantidade, despesas.id_despesa, despesas.despesa, despesas.valor_despesa, despesas.data_despesa, despesas.local_despesa, tipos.tipo from despesas inner join tipos on despesas.fk_id_tipo=tipos.id_tipo where year(data_despesa)='{$this->request->data['Despesa']['ano']}' and month(data_despesa)='{$this->request->data['Despesa']['mes']}'");
```

Eu já tentei fazer algo do tipo:

```
$despesas = $this->Despesa->query("select despesas.despesa, despesas.valor_despesa, despesas.data_despesa, despesas.local_despesa, tipos.tipo from despesas inner join tipos on despesas.fk_id_tipo=tipos.id_tipo where year(data_despesa)='{$this->request->data['Despesa']['ano']}' and month(data_despesa)='{$this->request->data['Despesa']['mes']}' in (select sum(despesas.valor_despesa) as total, count(despesas.id_despesa) as quantidade)");
```

Eu até posso fazer mais de uma busca, ou seja, dividir essa query em três 1. pegar os dados normalmente; 2. pegar o total e 3. pegar a quantidade. Mas pretendo fazer essa experiência.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia amigo, neste caso acho que o problema é de SQL. Sempre que você usar funções de agregação como o SUM ou a COUNT o SQL retornará a SOMA ou a CONTAGEM em uma só linha, a menos que você agrupe (GROUP) os resultados.

Teria que saber certinho como é a sua tabela do banco para poder ajudar melhor, mas você pode ver sobre as funções de agregação do SQL no Google.

Espero ter ajudado.